# Entity Framework Reference constraint error on delete when using selectmany

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

**Edit:** Please read carefully, I have and issue **Loading** data for without cartesian production. Deleting data works fine if the references are loaded properly.

I'm trying to delete a large group of entities, However due to a many-to-many assoication `OwnerRoles` whenever I try to delete them I receive an error:

> SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_OwnerRoles_aspnet_Roles_RoleId"

When I try to avoid cartesian production by loading the aspnet_roles using a select many,

```
var rolesQuery = context.Organizations
       .Where(x => x.OrganizationId == organizationId)
       .SelectMany(x => x.aspnet_Roles);

var roles = rolesQuery.ToArray();
rolesQuery.SelectMany(x => x.Permissions).Load();
rolesQuery.SelectMany(x => x.Organizations).Load();
```

The assoicated OwnerRoles is not loaded, so when I attempt to remove all of the references:

```
roles.ForEach(r => r.Organizations.ToArray().ForEach(o => r.Organizations.Remove(o)));

context.Permissions.RemoveRange(roles.SelectMany(x => x.Permissions));
context.aspnet_Roles.RemoveRange(roles);

context.SaveChanges();
```

There is nothing loaded to remove so, I get my referencial constraint when deleting.

This is my db structure

```
Organizations: * => * aspnet_Roles (Many To Many connected by intermediate table **OwnerRoles**)
aspnet_Roles: 1 => * permissions (aspnet_Roles has many permissions)
```

Notes:

1. I cannot use CascadeOnDelete
2. I'm using and Edmx with EntityFramework v6.2
3. I'd prefer to not use save changes multiple times.

Everything works fine if I use includes instead of SelectMany,  Because include loads the tables connecting However I would like to make seperate queries to avoid Cartesian production, so the result set sent back over the wire isn't so large.

How can I Load my data properly to avoid caretesian production, while still being able to delete many to many collections?

I'm looking for a way to explicitly load the references of a collection table (e.g there is no Poco class or DB set for that entity) OR I'm looking for a way to explicitly delete from EntityFramework (with out calling a stored procedure because that will circumvent the audit log)

Comment: Are you sure you deleting it in the right order, if you do foreign key will not be violated. You may need to commit what you deleted in the first table and requery second table to avoid the error.

Comment: @bestinamir, Yes, everything Works when I use includes, When I use selectmany it doesn't attempt to delete the references.

Comment: What exactly do you want to delete? Roles and permissions?

Comment: Best to my knowledge, you MUST perform two different operations.  1st to delete all the related "Permissions" and 2nd to delete all the related "aspnet_Roles".  Technically both should be in a separate "Transaction".

Comment: The other option is (if possible), create a Stored Procedure which performs DELETE based on your preferred sequence.  The input parameter to the SP would be 'organizationId'.

Comment: @GertArnold I'm operating on a modified version of OpenId, I'm allowing functionality which deletes an organization, so I need to clear out the roles. The built in membership does clear my custom tables

Comment: @Indar-AIS the problem isn't the Delete the problem is the load

Comment: Then again, what do you want to see deleted by your own code? Only `OwnerRoles` records? Your question lacks a clear description of what you're trying to achieve. "I'm trying to delete a large group of entities" + "I'm not trying to delete the organizations" leaves a lot of room for speculation.

Comment: @GertArnold, Sorry I've editing the question so it's more explicit

Comment: Your assumption that `Include` creates a cartesian product is not correct because EF will create unique role instances and figure out the correct associations. So just use `Include`.

Comment: BTW, the best way to tackle this kind of problem is to pull the junction class into your class model. It will slightly complicate querying the many-to-many navigations but bring a lot of comfort otherwise.

Comment: @GertArnold, yeah I usually just add a bs field to the table so it generates a poco class, but Its not my project.  How can I pull the junction class in with out using code first is there a way in the edmx editor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Problem

Additionally to the 3 standard ways of loading related data (eager, explicit and lazy), EF6 supports another way through a process called "navigation property fix-up", which is utilized by queries like your

```
rolesQuery.SelectMany(x => x.Permissions).Load();
```

Note that the name `Load` is a bit misleading. `Load` is EF custom extension method which simply executes the query and iterates the result set, similar to `ToList`, but without creating a list.

The first 3 methods work for any type of relationship. However the last doesn't work for many-to-many with implicit link entity relationships, because there is no way to specify the "link" entity in the LINQ query, so the following

```
rolesQuery.SelectMany(x => x.Organizations).Load();
```

and

```
context.Organizations.Load();
```

are equivalent - both return (and load) `Organization` entities.

The standard solution is to use some of the 3 standard ways. But eager loading generates huge union data set, while explicit and lazy loading generate N + 1 database queries.

### Solution

Many-to-many with implicit link entity relationships are implemented as *independent associations* and are maintained purely by the context change tracker. `DbContext` APIs do not provide a way to maintain such relationships state, but as mentioned in the [Creating and modifying relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships#creating-and-modifying-relationships) section of the EF6 documentation, `ObjectContext` APIs do with [ChangeRelationshipState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.core.objects.objectstatemanager.changerelationshipstate?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) method of the [ObjectStateManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.core.objects.objectstatemanager?view=entity-framework-6.2.0).

Following is a custom generic extension method which solves the problem by utilizing the aforementioned method. The essential part is

```
// Query to retrieve IEnumerable<Tuple<TSourceKey, TTarget>> from database
// and group it by TSourceKey in memory
var groupedLinksQuery = sourceDbQuery
    .SelectLinks(keySelector, collectionSelector)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(e => e.Item1, e => e.Item2);
// Execute the query and perform the fix-up
foreach (var group in groupedLinksQuery)
{
    var source = sourceDbSet.Find(group.Key);
    foreach (var target in group)
        stateManager.ChangeRelationshipState(source, target, collectionPropertyName, EntityState.Unchanged);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
var roles = rolesQuery.ToArray();
rolesQuery.SelectMany(role => role.Permissions).Load();
context.LoadLinks(rolesQuery, role => role.Id, role => role.Organizations); // <--
```

Full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace System.Data.Entity
{
    public static partial class EF6Extensions
    {
        public static void LoadLinks<TSource, TSourceKey, TTarget>(this DbContext dbContext, IQueryable<TSource> sourceDbQuery, Expression<Func<TSource, TSourceKey>> keySelector, Expression<Func<TSource, ICollection<TTarget>>> collectionSelector)
            where TSource : class
            where TTarget : class
        {
            // Disable AutoDetectChanges for better performance
            bool autoDetectChanges = dbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled;
            dbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            try
            {
                var sourceDbSet = dbContext.Set<TSource>();
                var collectionPropertyName = ((MemberExpression)collectionSelector.Body).Member.Name;
                var stateManager = dbContext.GetObjectStateManager();
                // Query to retrieve IEnumerable<Tuple<TSourceKey, TTarget>> from database
                // and group it by TSourceKey in memory
                var groupedLinksQuery = sourceDbQuery
                    .SelectLinks(keySelector, collectionSelector)
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupBy(e => e.Item1, e => e.Item2);
                // Execute the query and perform the fix-up
                foreach (var group in groupedLinksQuery)
                {
                    var source = sourceDbSet.Find(group.Key);
                    foreach (var target in group)
                        stateManager.ChangeRelationshipState(source, target, collectionPropertyName, EntityState.Unchanged);
                }
            }
            finally { dbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = autoDetectChanges; }
        }

        static IQueryable<Tuple<TSourceKey, TTarget>> SelectLinks<TSource, TSourceKey, TTarget>(this IQueryable<TSource> sourceQuery, Expression<Func<TSource, TSourceKey>> keySelector, Expression<Func<TSource, ICollection<TTarget>>> collectionSelector)
        {
            // sourceQuery.SelectMany(source => source.Collection, (source, target) => Tuple(source.Key, target))
            var source = keySelector.Parameters[0];
            var target = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TTarget), "target");
            var resultType = typeof(Tuple<TSourceKey, TTarget>);
            var constructor = resultType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(TSourceKey), typeof(TTarget) });
            var args = new[] { keySelector.Body, target };
            var members = new[] { resultType.GetProperty("Item1"), resultType.GetProperty("Item2") };
            var body = Expression.New(constructor, args, members);
            var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TTarget, Tuple<TSourceKey, TTarget>>>(
                body, source, target);
            return sourceQuery.SelectMany(collectionSelector.AsEnumerable(), selector);
        }

        static Expression<Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TTarget>>> AsEnumerable<TSource, TTarget>(this Expression<Func<TSource, ICollection<TTarget>>> collectionSelector)
            => Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TTarget>>>(collectionSelector.Body, collectionSelector.Parameters);

        public static ObjectContext GetObjectContext(this IObjectContextAdapter source) => source.ObjectContext;

        public static ObjectStateManager GetObjectStateManager(this IObjectContextAdapter source) => source.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** The above executes 2 db queries and the second contains duplicate `TTarget` records paired with `TSourceKey`. The difference with include is that it eliminates the `TSource` columns from the query.

Retrieving only the data needed w/o duplicates is possible, and requires executing 3 db queries:

```
public static partial class EF6Extensions
{
    public static void LoadLinks<TSource, TTarget, TSourceKey, TTargetKey>(this DbContext dbContext, IQueryable<TSource> sourceQuery, Expression<Func<TSource, ICollection<TTarget>>> collectionSelector, Expression<Func<TSource, TSourceKey>> sourceKeySelector, Expression<Func<TTarget, TTargetKey>> targetKeySelector)
        where TSource : class
        where TTarget : class
    {
        // Disable AutoDetectChanges for better performance
        bool autoDetectChanges = dbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled;
        dbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        try
        {
            var sourceDbSet = dbContext.Set<TSource>();
            var targetDbSet = dbContext.Set<TTarget>();
            // Query to retrieve link keys from database
            var linksDbQuery = sourceQuery.SelectLinks(collectionSelector, sourceKeySelector, targetKeySelector);
            // Query to retrieve distinct target keys from database
            var targetKeysDbQuery = linksDbQuery.Select(e => e.Item2).Distinct();
            // Query to retrieve unique target entities
            var targetDbQuery = targetDbSet
                .Join(targetKeysDbQuery, targetKeySelector, key => key, (target, key) => target);
            // Execute the target entities query and build map by Id in memory
            var targetMap = targetDbQuery
                .ToDictionary(targetKeySelector.Compile());
            // Execute the links query and perform the fix-up 
            var stateManager = dbContext.GetObjectStateManager();
            var collectionPropertyName = ((MemberExpression)collectionSelector.Body).Member.Name;
            var sourceMap = new Dictionary<TSourceKey, TSource>();
            foreach (var link in linksDbQuery)
            {
                if (!sourceMap.TryGetValue(link.Item1, out var source))
                    sourceMap.Add(link.Item1, source = sourceDbSet.Find(link.Item1));
                var target = targetMap[link.Item2];
                stateManager.ChangeRelationshipState(source, target, collectionPropertyName, EntityState.Unchanged);
            }
        }
        finally { dbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = autoDetectChanges; }
    }

    static IQueryable<Tuple<TSourceKey, TTargetKey>> SelectLinks<TSource, TTarget, TSourceKey, TTargetKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> sourceQuery, Expression<Func<TSource, ICollection<TTarget>>> collectionSelector, Expression<Func<TSource, TSourceKey>> sourceKeySelector, Expression<Func<TTarget, TTargetKey>> targetKeySelector)
    {
        // sourceQuery.SelectMany(source => source.Collection, (source, target) => Tuple(source.Key, target.Key))
        var source = sourceKeySelector.Parameters[0];
        var target = targetKeySelector.Parameters[0];
        var resultType = typeof(Tuple<TSourceKey, TTargetKey>);
        var constructor = resultType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(TSourceKey), typeof(TTargetKey) });
        var args = new[] { sourceKeySelector.Body, targetKeySelector.Body };
        var members = new[] { resultType.GetProperty("Item1"), resultType.GetProperty("Item2") };
        var body = Expression.New(constructor, args, members);
        var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TTarget, Tuple<TSourceKey, TTargetKey>>>(
            body, source, target);
        return sourceQuery.SelectMany(collectionSelector.AsEnumerable(), selector);
    }
}
```

and the usage requires passing a selectors for both keys e.g.

```
context.LoadLinks(rolesQuery, role => role.Organizations, role => role.Id, organization => organization.Id));
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect, this looks right just give me a day or so to verify!

Comment: There is an issue with the extensions.  It acts exactly as an include. e.g `context.LoadLinks(rolesQuery, r => r.RoleId, r => r.Organizations)` If run this with no roles or organizations loaded.  It loads both organization and roles. Which means it will create the cartesian production

Comment: Not exactly. If you have A, B, and AB, a.Include(a.Bs) will create query with all fields from A and all fields from B. Of course there will be duplicate As and duplicate Bs. The above approach eliminates A fields. There still will be duplicate B records associated with different AId, so if this is what you mean with "cartesian production", yes, but the query columns will be much less. Loading w/o any repetition is possible, but requires executing 3 db queries (as opposed to 2 in this approach).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: I know this probably isn't the best way to go about contacting you, but you've helped me several times in the past with EF related things, I've created a [bountied question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63177215/1938988) about EF if you have time and are interested

Comment: @johnny5 Thanks, really appreciate. And glad being of little help from time to time :)

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate all of the help you've given me.  All of you're answers show extreme expertise,  and Its saved me hours of time coding :)